# Do some operation in a django serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have created a serializer, which will just call some util functions, without doing anything else. Here is my serializer:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    member = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ['member']

    def validate_member(self, value):
        try:
            member = patients_models.Member.objects.get(id=value)
        except Member.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError('Member with given id not found')
        else:
            return member
```

I just want to validate my data, and then call the utility functions by passing this member object, so which is the best place to call those functions? Or should I call it in the view itself?

Comment: It's totally fine define validation in serializers, also this is suggested by official docs, check it out https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#function-based

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call your utility function after validation then it would  make sense to call it in a serializer rather than your view
and you might only want to call your util function if the validation is successful

Comment: Hi, I will be calling another api after registration is successful. That's why I need this api.